# Getting GIT versions from RTC

Tags: git, rtc

we have RTC 4.0.4 installed and we are using GIT. 
What do we need in order to receive the versions from GIT to our version field in RTC?

Answer (score 0):

For updating any work item field, you have the choice between the web api or Java api presented in [RtcSdk20](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/RtcSdk20) (you need a -- free -- account to access those sections).

Any (work item-related) action that you can do on the RTC client can be done through a web query.

The rest of the answer illustrates modifying the "links change sets" field, but you can adapt it to modify other fields as well

---

If by "version field" in RTC you are referring to  the change sets sections of the "links" tab of a Work Item, like this one:

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/3.0/distributed-scm/images/work_item_links.png]

Then [this article uses git hooks](https://jazz.net/library/article/194/#Git), and, through a series of curl command, instructs RTC to add a link back to the gitweb url of that commit.
Here is the [post-commit hook](https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/2.0/source-control/git-integration/hooks/commit-msg.sample).

Comment: Thanks a lot! but that's not what i was looking for. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

No. not what i was looking for. i need versions from GIT (tags, build numbers etc) to go to found_in field in RTC. that way i will not have to maintain this field manually.

Comment: Please delete this and edit your question: this isn't a forum. Carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/about.